# Как называется стандарт правильного формирования?

Tags: стандарт

Нужно название стандарта формирования указательных структур, а то есть к примеру есть консольная программа для которой задается параметры вида:

```
example_program [s|t] {a|b} <prim>
```

Забыл название этого стандарта и не могу вспомнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется - Extended Backus–Naur Form , а его общепринятый международный стандарт ISO/IEC 14977